# Can a user-chosen image be inserted directly into a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, html, image, jfilechooser, jeditorpane

What I am trying to do is open up a JFilechooser that filters jpeg,gif and png images, then gets the user's selection and inserts it into the JEditorPane. Can this be done? or am i attempting something impossible? Here is a sample of my program.(insert is a JMenuItem and mainText is a JEditorPane)

```
insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JFileChooser imageChooser = new JFileChooser();
      imageChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Format","jpg","jpeg","gif","png"));
                int choice = imageChooser.showOpenDialog(mainText);
                if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                mainText.add(imageChooser.getSelectedFile());
                }
        }
    });
```

What i tried to do is use the add method, i know it's wrong but just to give you an idea of what i'm trying to do.
Before you complain, i'm sorry about the code formatting, i don't really know all the conventions of what is considered good or bad style.
Thank you very much.

This is the part of the code i use to save the html file.

```
else if (e.getSource() == save) {
        JFileChooser saver = new JFileChooser();
        saver.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".html (webpage format)" , "html"));
        int option = saver.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(saver.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                out.write(mainText.getText());
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easier to just use a JTextPane. Then you can use insertIcon(...) anywhere in the text.

Edit:

I have never had much luck trying to manipulate HTML but I've used code like the following before:

```
HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit)textPane.getEditorKit();
text = "<a href=\"abc\">hyperlink</a>";
editorKit.insertHTML(doc, textPane.getCaretPosition(), text, 0, 0, HTML.Tag.A);
```

So presumably the code would be similiar for the IMG tag.

Comment: thank you, THIS was what i was looking for, i somehow supposed that JEditorPane and JTextPane would have the same methods, since they are really alike.
thank you

Comment: yes, but is it possible that when i save the file as an html, i can open it with my browser and the image will show up this way? because that is my only concern now.

Comment: The two components are used for different purposes. If you need the text in HTML format then this won't work. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
mainText.setContentType("text/html");
String image = String.format("<img src=\"%s\">", imageChooser.getSelectedFile());
mainText.setText(image);
```

Comment: thank you so much, i had been in a trial and error situation with this for days until i decided to ask for help here, thanks.

Comment: and what if i wanted to add it at the end of some text i've already written? I mean , i cant use setText(mainText.getText() + image); because that would put it outside of the body tags, what could i do in that case?

Comment: @JIM, what I would do is String text = mainText.getText(), then using String's substring() method cut off the last 7 characters (</body>).  Then append your <img>, and append a new </body>.  The substring call might look like text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 7);