# Reload EditorPane

Tags: java, image, jeditorpane

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951357/can-a-user-chosen-image-be-inserted-directly-into-a-jeditorpane): what I was searching for but still I have some issues.

This is my action code:

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {

    jEditorPane1.setContentType("text/html");


    int returnVal = FileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == FileChooser1.APPROVE_OPTION) {


String image = String.format("<img src=\"%s\">", FileChooser1.getSelectedFile());
    jEditorPane1.setText(image);

    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens, as you can see the image is not loaded.
http://postimg.org/image/agc665ih1/

But if I save the file (with save button) and reopen the same file (with open button), the image is there and is perfectly loaded.

I already tried the .repaint() and .revalidate() methods, but is not working..
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This may be problem in setting up path in JEditorPane page. use this:

```
String image = String.format("<img src=\"%s\">", FileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getPath());
```

I am assuming that you have already selected appropriate editorKit for JEditorPane.

Comment: No I get the same result :/
For the JEditorPane I selected the HTMLeditorKit(), the code look like that:
  jEditorPane1.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());

Comment: I think that this is not the problem but I will paste the code as soon as I can answer my own question, because I have to wait some hours because of my reputation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So now I can answer with my code. I am using this class for the file chooser:

```
import java.io.File;
```

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

class jpgfilter extends FileFilter {

```
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() || file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".jpg");
    }

    public String getDescription() {

        return "JPG image (*.jpg)";
    }
```

}

And in my main class I have this:

```
FileChooser1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    FileChooser1.setDialogTitle("Choose your image:");
    FileChooser1.setFileFilter(new jpgfilter());
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found some kind of a solution but I think there is really too much code and that I should do it easily..I actually insert the image and simultaneously save and open the content of the EditorPane as .html file.

The code:

```
    jEditorPane1.setContentType("text/html");

    int returnVal = FileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == FileChooser1.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        String image = String.format("<img src=\"%s\">", FileChooser1
                .getSelectedFile().getPath());

        jEditorPane1.setText(image);

        String type = jEditorPane1.getContentType();

        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                "/Library/java_test/temp" + ".html"));

        Document doc = jEditorPane1.getDocument();
        int length = doc.getLength();

        if (type.endsWith("/rtf")) {
            // Saving RTF - use the OutputStream
            try {
                jEditorPane1.getEditorKit().write(os, doc, 0, length);
                os.close();
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            }
        } else {
            // Not RTF - use a Writer.
            Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            jEditorPane1.write(w);
            w.close();
        }

        String url = "file:///" + "/Library/java_test/temp" + ".html";

        jEditorPane1.setPage(url);

    }
```